# List of tables as a section with number

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

How can I get the list of tables as a section in an article document, so it will be listed in the table of contents with number?

For the list of figures I have used this:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoffigures{%
    \section{\listfigurename}% Used to be \section*{\listfigurename}
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
    {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
    \@starttoc{lof}%
}
\makeatother
```

but for the list of tables it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are classes, which support numbering of list of figures, list of tables etc. For example with `scrartcl` you can use:

```latex
\documentclass[emulatestandardclasses,listof=numbered]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\section{Test}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image}
  \caption{Testfigure}
  \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lcr}
    left & center & right
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Test Table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: with scrartcl and buildin feature]

For the standard `article` class you can achieve the same, using the KOMA-Script package [`tocbasic`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocbasic), that provides several more features:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\setuptoc{lof}{numbered}
\setuptoc{lot}{numbered}
\renewcommand*{\listoffigures}{\listoftoc[\listfigurename]{lof}}
\renewcommand*{\listoftables}{\listoftoc[\listtablename]{lot}}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\section{Test}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image}
  \caption{Testfigure}
  \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lcr}
    left & center & right
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Test Table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: with article and tocbasic]

However, if you'd prefer to adapt your solution for the list of figures also for the list of tables, you have to copy the redefinition of `\listoffigures` and replace all “`figure`” with “`table`” and “`lof`” (the file extension of the auxiliary file used for the list of figures) by “`lot`” (the file extension of the auxiliary file used for the list of tables):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoffigures{%
    \section{\listfigurename}% Used to be \section*{\listfigurename}
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
    {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
    \@starttoc{lof}%
}
\renewcommand\listoftables{%
    \section{\listtablename}% Used to be \section*{\listfigurename}
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listtableame}%
    {\MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
    \@starttoc{lot}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\section{Test}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image}
  \caption{Testfigure}
  \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lcr}
    left & center & right
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Test Table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The result is again the same as already shown.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you use the `article` document class. I therefore suggest you employ the [tocbibind](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind) package and use that package's `\tocfile` command to tell LaTeX to number the List of Tables and the List of Figures.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % no line item for ToC in ToC
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{%
   \begingroup
   \tocsection
   \tocfile{\listfigurename}{lof}
   \endgroup}
\renewcommand{\listoftables}{%
   \begingroup
   \tocsection
   \tocfile{\listtablename}{lot}
   \endgroup}
   
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} % optional
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\mdseries} % don't bold-face page numbers
   
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\listoftables

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Intro}
\lipsum[1-6]
\begin{figure}[htpb]\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{table}[htpb]\caption{A table}\end{table}
\lipsum[7-9]

\section{Outro}
\lipsum[1-6]
\begin{figure}[htpb]\caption{Another figure}\end{figure}
\begin{table}[htpb]\caption{Another table}\end{table}
\lipsum[7-9]

\end{document}
```